Voltage regulation for backup battery power circuit
I am building a GPS tracker where I need to have the option to drive the device from an external power source up to 40 V and have an internal 3.7 V backup battery.
My GSM Modem (Quectel M66) needs 4 V and 2 A (peak) and the rest of the circuit needs a 3.3 V rail.
I am using LM2596S-5 as the main regulator and a TP4056 to recharge the backup battery. I have a small MOSFET driven power path switching circuit, that allows power from the LM2596 and when the external power source is off, it allows power from 3.7 V backup battery.
So the situation is at the output of the power path switching MOSFET, I have a voltage that varies from 2.5 V (The cutoff voltage of the backup battery from the over discharge protection circuit) TO 5 V (power from LM2596).
From here I need 4 V 2 A for the GSM module and once I can get it, I can use a 3.3 V LDO to distribute power to the rest of the circuit.
I am trying to use SX1308 boost convert to have a stable 4 V out of the voltage range specified above. Can anyone please guide me if I am moving to the right direction?
Datasheet of SX1308
https://www.sunrom.com/download/458.pdf


Missing input decoupling capacitor for your boost converter.

Hi @winny yes, definitely, some minor adjustments are needed. But I wanted to be sure I am moving on the right path. The most important question is will SX1308 or MT3608 will be able to output 4V when the input is at 5V (running from external power source) by working as a buck converter.

Datasheet links to L1 and L2? Have you simulated your circuit?

No, have not simulated yet. I did not find SPICE for MT3608 or SX1308

You need  a device that is sold as a buck boost converter.  Looks like the sx1308 is boost only. Also, it is doubtful that you can supply 2A at 4 V with this device, when driven by 2.5 v.

Enter your entire batter voltage range into TI webench and 4 V 2 A output and it will give you several options with complete BOMs and schematics.

Thanks, have tried it.. gave me few schematics and within budget..
